# Trouble understanding statement order in Chisel

Tags: hdl, chisel, printf-debugging

Here is a simple module containing a down counter:

```
import chisel3.util.{Valid, DeqIO}
class Input(WIDTH : Int) extends Bundle {
  val x = UInt(WIDTH.W)
}
class Output(WIDTH : Int) extends Bundle {
  val y = UInt(WIDTH.W)
}
class DownCount(WIDTH : Int) extends Module {
  val io  = IO(new Bundle {
    val in  = DeqIO(new Input(WIDTH))
    val out = Output(Valid(new Output(WIDTH)))
  })
  val i = Reg(UInt(WIDTH.W))
  val p = RegInit(false.B)

  printf("i = %d, p = %b, out.valid = %b\n",
    i, p, io.out.valid)
  io.in.ready := !p
  io.out.valid := false.B
  io.out.bits.y := 10.U
  when (p) {
    i := i - 1.U
    when (i === 0.U) {
      printf("Before setting out.valid = %b\n", io.out.valid)
      p := false.B
      // Here the register is set to 1.
      io.out.valid := true.B
    }
  }.otherwise {
    when (io.in.valid) {
      printf("Initializing\n")
      i := WIDTH.U - 1.U
      p := true.B
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the output after applying the `clock.step()` function on the module a few times:

```
i =    0, p = 0, out.valid = 0
Initializing
i =    7, p = 1, out.valid = 0
i =    6, p = 1, out.valid = 0
i =    5, p = 1, out.valid = 0
i =    4, p = 1, out.valid = 0
i =    3, p = 1, out.valid = 0
i =    2, p = 1, out.valid = 0
i =    1, p = 1, out.valid = 0
i =    0, p = 1, out.valid = 1
Before setting out.valid = 1     <-- why is it 1 here??
i =  255, p = 0, out.valid = 0
```

How on earth can `io.out.valid` be 1 (true) *before* it is assigned the `true.B` value? Is Chisel reordering printf statement in some weird way?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be normal behavior. With the `:=` operator, the left-value will be written with right value at the end of clock cycle.
`out.valid` is still `true.B` just after `false.B` assignation.

```
// i =    0, p = 1, out.valid = 1
  printf("i = %d, p = %b, out.valid = %b\n",i, p, io.out.valid) 
  io.in.ready := !p
  io.out.valid := false.B
// Here, io.out.valid is still true.B if printf was true.B
// false.B will be written at the end of cycle,
//  except if another connection write true.B
  io.out.bits.y := 10.U
  when (p) {
    i := i - 1.U
    when (i === 0.U) {
      printf("Before setting out.valid = %b\n", io.out.valid)
      p := false.B
      // Here the register is set to 1.
      io.out.valid := true.B  // Will be set to true.B (but was already true.B)
    }
  }.otherwise {
    when (io.in.valid) {
      printf("Initializing\n")
      i := WIDTH.U - 1.U
      p := true.B
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. In the same clock cycle i is zero, io.out.valid should be false since the change happens in the *next* clock cycle? io.out.valid is set to true one clock cycle earlier than it should. I.e `i === 0.U` should be checking the current value of the register not its next value.

Comment: It checks the current value yes. But `i := i - 1.U` is setting the next value.

Comment: `:=` operator is like `<=` operator in VHDL or Verilog it's non-blocking assignment.

Comment: So when is `io.out.valid` set to 1? It must happen in exactly the same clock cycle that `i` is set to -1 (255). But that is not the case, `io.out.valid` is set to 1 when `i` is set to 0.

Comment: Right after the clock, 0 is loaded in the register. So ```When (i===0.U)``` would be executed. Now, the ```io.out.valid``` is set to ```true.B``` and at the same time you're printing its value. So, ```i``` is 0 and ```io.out.valid``` is ```true```. Same as the output.